# JWT Invalid signature from one website, but no errors with another. Extra properties of user object get added to token

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, backend

### Problem

I have two websites. One is production, but a very very old version.
Another is just localhost where I'm currently testing it.
After involving [NextAuthJS](https://next-auth.js.org) to the NextJS website, I need to integrate my NextAuthJS session provider to the remote ExpressJS backend.

1. I make a request to /login ->

   1. on remote backend I generate a JWT token, and get full user details.
   2. then I send data to the NextJS website.
   3. using NextAuthJS, store it in a cookie.

---

2. In case I need to get any user specific details, such as saved videos:

   1. I make a request from NextJS website.
   2. On remote ExpressJS backend I decode the token which I receive in the 'authorization' bearer
      header, to get user's details...

---

And boom! Here the error message repeats shouting at me: "JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature"

That doesn't happen on the production website, even though the remote backend is one link for both the production and development.

### What I have tried and explored

What I noticed using [JWT token debugger](https://token.dev/) is that

1. In case of the production website's request, which doesn't give any errors, the decoded user consists of { id, role }. As EXPECTED.
   [image: screenshot of the jwt decoder]
2. But in case of local version's request, which gives error message, it shows that the user consists of the whole user details object stored in the DB.
   And debugger also changes the decryption algorithm automatically from HS256 to HS512. And, even though showing the encrypted message, it says 'token verification failed'.
   [image: JWT token debugger]

---

**Token from local, gives error:**
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.ZCnnNZ2a7aeO6GCnyhnWYGMX-4kkJX75ZyzG52lSiWxUBIawXrA37882HFwo_3r6-I3JrrYNv270vxfsMwyBlw

---

**Token from production, works as expected :**
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTdjMWEzN2EwYjAzMjExNzE1M2Q0NzMiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTYzNjI5MTY3MywiZXhwIjoxNjM2Mzc4MDczfQ.bqY6y0_lmX5dBAHemgv_9UFuupwLBBDcyFpAdXgCiH8

---

**JWT Secret : jdgfaiodsugfaileufliaeruy**

---

**Code of decoding token and getting user data is:**

```
exports.requireSignin = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.headers.authorization) {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    console.log( 'token is', token );
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        console.log( err, 'Token given', token, 'Token secret', process.env.JWT_SECRET );
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "Token has been expired!" });
      }
      req.user = decoded;
      console.log( decoded );
    });
    // const user = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    // console.log(user);
    // req.user = user;
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: "Authorization required" });
  }
  next();
  //jwt.decode()
};
```

---

**Code of GENERATING that token:**

```
exports.signin = async (req, res) => {
  
  
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec((error, user) => {
    if (error){ console.log( 'login error', error ); return res.status(400).json({ error }); }
   
    if (user) {
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.hash_password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log( req.body.password, user.hash_password );
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: "Something's wrong, Please try again" });
        }
        if (!result) {
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
        }

        if (user.approval.isApproved === false)
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ error: "Please verify your account" });

        if (user.isSuspended === true)
          return res.status(400).json({ error: "You have been temporarily suspended, please contact support" });

        const token = jwt.sign(
          { _id: user._id, role: user.role },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET,
          {
            expiresIn: "1d",
          }
        );
        console.log( process.env.JWT_SECRET, token, user._id, user.role );

        // some unnecessary code ...

          res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            token: "Bearer " + token,
            ProfileImageBaseUrl: ProfileImageBaseUrl,
            user: {
              _id,
              firstName,
              lastName,
              email,
              role,
              jobRole,
              videoGoal,
              profilePicture,
              createdBy,
              approval,
              accessType,
              resetPassToken,
              branding,
              sub_status
            },
          });

           
            
        })
       
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Something's wrong, Please try again" });
    }
  });
};
```

---

**A) WHEN I GET AN ERROR, The LOGS I receive from my backend are:**

---

***Sign in controller***, console.log( process.env.JWT_SECRET, token, user._id, user.role ) is

jdgfaiodsugfaileufliaeruy eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTdjMWEzN2EwYjAzMjExNzE1M2Q0NzMiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTYzNjI5MTY3MywiZXhwIjoxNjM2Mzc4MDczfQ.bqY6y0_lmX5dBAHemgv_9UFuupwLBBDcyFpAdXgCiH8 617c1a37a0b032117153d473 user

---

***Require sign in controller*** ,console.log( err, 'Token given', token, 'Token secret', process.env.JWT_SECRET ) is:

Token given eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.ZCnnNZ2a7aeO6GCnyhnWYGMX-4kkJX75ZyzG52lSiWxUBIawXrA37882HFwo_3r6-I3JrrYNv270vxfsMwyBlw Token secret jdgfaiodsugfaileufliaeruy

---

**B) When no error, these are:**

---

***Require sign in*** : token is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTdjMWEzN2EwYjAzMjExNzE1M2Q0NzMiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTYzNjI5MTYyNSwiZXhwIjoxNjM2Mzc4MDI1fQ.K-inQfI77mepKjkG_5g4obr3sfcVnDwCOXeQlDPra00

---

***Sign in*** :

jdgfaiodsugfaileufliaeruy eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTdjMWEzN2EwYjAzMjExNzE1M2Q0NzMiLCJyb2xlIjoidXNlciIsImlhdCI6MTYzNjI5MTYyNSwiZXhwIjoxNjM2Mzc4MDI1fQ.K-inQfI77mepKjkG_5g4obr3sfcVnDwCOXeQlDPra00 617c1a37a0b032117153d473 user

### My thoughts

I feel like it is just something simple I just don't notice, ***I've been trying to fix it for 9 hours,*** but I haven't determined what yet.

Please, help me, guys!

Any help or hints are highly appreciated!

### Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You'll need to find the code that generates these wrong tokens. Apparently it's not the `jwt.sign({ _id: user._id, role: user.role },  process.env.JWT_SECRET,  {expiresIn: "1d"});`

Comment: Are you sure the secret is correct for the development stage?

Comment: @eol, first, thank you so much for your reply!

Yes, the secret is fully correct, but I found problem in next-auth-js-specific thing.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you lots lots lots for your reply!

It appeared that my token that I was getting from remote backend, NextAuthJS was hashing, so there was a double encryption.

I moved from using the jwt token from cookie to using the token stored in user object which I get from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone who helped me with this! @Bergi and @eol!

***The problem was nextauthjs specific and not conserned about expressjs, as it appeared.***

So I don't get token returned by nextauthjs anymore.

Instead, I get token from user object's authToken property, stored in the session.

---

So it is like:

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ router, ctx }) => {
  const session = await getSession(ctx);
  if (router.asPath === '/login' || router.asPath === '/register') {
    return { session: session };
  }
  if (!session || !session.user) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: '/login',
    });
    ctx.res.end();
  }
  console.log('Access token', session.accessToken);
  axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    authorization: `${session.accessToken}`,
  };
  return { token: `${session.accessToken}`, session: session };
};
```